# Can't run containers for python file

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm new on docker and I've been trying to create 5 containers for:

1. nginx
2. db
3. 3 instances of python app by using the command:

   `docker-compose up -d --build --scale app=3`

I followed some tutorials and successfully created these two containers:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                 NAMES
27532d44e591   nginx:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   31 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp    whist-nginx-1
3873501f7cce   mysql          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago    Up 6 minutes   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   whist-db-1
```

But for some reason my 3 containers of my `app.py` instances are not running. What am I doing worng?

This is my directory tree:

[image]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9                 

WORKDIR /app                     

COPY . /app                       

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  

EXPOSE 80                        

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

requirements.txt :
`flask`

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:                                        
  nginx:                                          
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro     
    depends_on:                                    
      - app

  app:
    build:
      context: ./app
    ports:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app_logs:/app/logs                     
  
  db: 
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./db/logs:/var/log/mysql
volumes:
  app_logs:
  db_data:
  db_logs:
```

nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1000;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app:8000;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the image of your own app. You build `nginx` and `mysql` from their own images so of course docker can build them without issue.
To fix your app image, firstly, you should try something like:

- Structure of your app

```
your-app
|____ app.py
|____ requirements.txt
|____ Dockerfile
```

- app.py file

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, Docker!'
```

- Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "-m" , "flask", "run"]
```

After successful building your own app image, you can build it with other services.